# How to use context in a Library?

Tags: java, android, lib

I want to create a .jar library in android studio. In my project I would like to use "Context" because I am using another .jar library and it needs a context as a argument. I learned that, we shouldn't use context in .jar libraries from my researches.

Q1: Is it possible to use Context similar android structures in java library? If yes, how?

Q2: If no, should I create "Android Library" instead of "Java Library" when creating new module in android studio?

Comment: In java library, no way to reference to android framework package example Context, view, etc... You need create Android Library to do it

Comment: @Công Hải But jar library which I mentioned above is using Context ? How is it possible? I know that Android Library module creates .aar library.  Are there any other method to create .jar library from Android Library?